# Choose folder location and save it as a string with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, directory, frontend, absolute-path

I'm new to angular and I'm currently struggling with a functionality I'm trying to implement.
What I'm trying to do, is to pick a folder and save its absolute path as a string, similar to when you install a new program and there is a dialog where you choose where to install the program. I'm using the following line and it shows me only folders, but when I choose one, it doesn't select the folder itself, but all the items that are in there.

```
<input type="file" id="filepicker" name="fileList" (change)="saveFolderLocation($event)" webkitdirectory/>
```

Comment: Please limit your question to a single topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask